# Scala safe way of converting String to Enumeration value

Tags: scala

Suppose I have enumeration:

```
object WeekDay extends Enumeration {
  type WeekDay = Value
  val Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun = Value
}
```

I would like to be able to convert String to WeekDay value and this is fine with:

```
scala> WeekDay.withName("Tue")
res10: WeekDay.Value = Tue
```

But if I pass some 'unknown' value, I'm getting exception:

```
scala> WeekDay.withName("Ou")
java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
  at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:322)
  at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:320)
  at scala.Enumeration.withName(Enumeration.scala:124)
  ... 32 elided
```

Is there some elegant way of safely convert String to Enumeration value?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can add a method to the enumeration to return an `Option[Value]`:

```
def withNameOpt(s: String): Option[Value] = values.find(_.toString == s)
```

Note: the existing `withName` method actually does precisely this, then calls `getOrElse` throwing the exception in the "else" case.

Comment: Wish this was part of the standard library, it's idiomatic Scala after all to have a safe way of doing things.

Comment: Might want to consider doing a case-insensitive comparison check

Comment: Doesn't work since Java 9. _ can no longer be used as an identifier.

Answer (score 11):

Building on top of @Shadowlands 's answer, I added this method to my enum to have a default `Unknown` value without dealing with options:

```
def withNameWithDefault(name: String): Value =
  values.find(_.toString.toLowerCase() == name.toLowerCase()).getOrElse(Unknown)
```

so the enum would look like this:

```
object WeekDay extends Enumeration {
  type WeekDay = Value
  val Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun, Unknown = Value

  def withNameWithDefault(name: String): Value = 
    values.find(_.toString.toLowerCase() == name.toLowerCase()).getOrElse(Unknown)
}
```