# How to convert string receive from query param to enums object in scala?

Tags: scala, enums

Ince from what I understand its not possible to receive Enum's as query params, what would be a proper way to change the strings i get to my enum object?

my route:

```
POST  /goto  controllers.goToAPlace(place: String)
```

my enum:

```
object Place extends Enumeration {
  type Place = Value
  val Italy, United States, Rome = Value
}
```

so now when i get it in `goToAPlace`  what is the proper way to convert it to my enums?

i want to be able to do something like this:

```
def goToAPlace(place: String) = {
if (place.isEqual(Italy)){
//do something
}
}
```

thanks

Comment: The fact that you got the string from a query param is irrelevant here, so it would have been much simpler to exclude it, but then your question reduces to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33593525/scala-safe-way-of-converting-string-to-enumeration-value), you could also find an answer to your question in Scala docs [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/Enumeration.html#withName(s:String):Enumeration.this.Value).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick and short way is:

```
Place.withName(place) == Italy
```

Note that the above code will throw an exception if the value is not found in the enumeration. Here is a safer way to deal with invalid input by using an Option:

```
Place.values.find(_.toString == place).contains(Italy)
```

Comment: If you're sure that the name matches one of the values in the enumeration, or if you'd really ant an exception to be thrown first convert your string to the enum using `Place.withName(place)` and then pattern match on it: `Place.withName(place) match { case Italy => ...}`, just remember ti import necessary stuff.

Answer (score -1):

In Scala, you can use a `match` statement if all you need is to take different actions:

```
place match {
  case "Italy" => // do something
  case "France" => // do something else
  case _ => // all others
}
```

You can also use a Java enum, in case the strings you receive are not valid Scala identifiers. This gives you a `Map<String, YourEnumType>`. You can use the map to convert `place: String` to your enum :

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
public enum WithFrom {
    TWO("one plus 1"), SIX("two plus 4");

    WithFrom(String expr) {
        this.expr = expr;
    }

    private final String expr;

    public static final Map<String, WithFrom> fromValue = Collections
            .unmodifiableMap(new HashMap<String, WithFrom>() {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 7205142682214758287L;

                {
                    for (WithFrom wf : WithFrom.values()) {
                        put(wf.expr, wf);
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: This is not exactly what's been asked. Using a Java enum is not an option here. Obviously PO wants to take advantage of Scala  `Enumeration`s and simply parse a string as an `Enumeration`

Comment: I have provided the `match` statement because it might do what he wants without having to convert to an enum. I've also provided a Java enum because it can be used in the cases where the strings he receives are not valid Scala identifiers.